# Join two tables with the same columns

Tags: mysql, sql, join

There are two tables T1 and T2. Both of them have 3 columns and 2 of them are the same with the same data in both tables. Let them be an ID, C1, C2 in the T1 and C1, C2, COM in the T2 table.

The thing is that all C1 data is present in T2, but C2 data can be missed.

I need to return a table with COM for each ID.

Tried

```
SELECT T1.ID, T2.COM
FROM T1 
LEFT JOIN T2 ON T1.C1 = T2.C1;
```

but it returns incorrect results.

Comment: Can you post some data or explain why the results are incorrect? Your SQL looks correct.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by 'C2 data can be missed', and provide sample data.

Comment: @smoore4 Here is my [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/afafd3/1)

Comment: What results do you need?

Comment: @Serge there may be NULL value in C2, while ID and C1 will have data

Comment: This query returns correct result. The human is in error.

Comment: @AntoineStas I need to have IDs returned like 1,2,3,4,..,16.... and each have a corresponding COM like W, X, Y, Y, .... Currently I have 1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4 and W, X, Y, W, X, Y...

Comment: Is this what you are looking for:
`SELECT T1.ID, T2.COM
FROM T1 
LEFT JOIN T2 ON T1.C1 = T2.C1 AND (T1.C2 IS NULL OR T1.C2 = T2.C2);`?

Comment: you need to join it on C1 and C2 which means that if any of them don't match you won't get anything back.

Comment: Is this the desired result?  1, W
2, X
3, NULL
4, NULL
16, Z

Comment: @Serge Still a bit incorrect as it returns ID: 1, 2, 16, 3, 4 and should be 1, 2, 3, 4, 16. Added `ORDER BY ID ASC`, but got 1, 16, 2, 3, 4

Comment: @smoore4 The desired result is 1 W, 2 X, 3 Y, 4 Y, ... 16 Z, ...

Comment: thats because you made id to varchar, change it to int and it will be ordered.

Comment: there is no way you can get 3Y with the current data

Comment: @isaace what can be changed?

Comment: it's not logical to expect 3Y because there is nothing really in the data that ties 3 to Y

Comment: @isaace I agree. Maybe this can help: COM is mapped in accordance with: IF A.C1 = 'A' AND A.C2 = 'A1' THEN COM = '1', ELIF A.C1 = 'A' AND A.C2 = 'A2' THEN COM = '2' ... ELIF A.C2 = 'A' THEN COM = '99'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as a summary: You need one and only one COM by ID (even If it doesn't exist in the second table) and you want the ID sorted ascending.

You need to add a join condition:

```
SELECT CAST(T1.ID as UNSIGNED) as ID, T2.COM
FROM T1 
LEFT JOIN T2 ON T1.C1 = T2.C1
AND (T1.C2 = T2.C2)  -- The first condition of this row is to handle the null value
OR (T1.C2 NOT IN (SELECT C2 FROM T2) AND T2.C2 = 'NA')
    ORDER BY CAST(T1.ID as UNSIGNED) -- To convert to int and sort ascending
```

Edit: To order the result ascending, you need to convert the ID into Integer and then order the result. Here is some [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cast-functions.html).

Edit2: Here it is for 3 and 4 it's the better method I think but I do not advise to do that usually

Comment: The results look better but still not the desired ones :(

Comment: Great, thanks a lot! Maybe you know what can be done to get 'Y' to ID 3 and 4 instead of NULL?

Comment: Can you change the data inside the database?

Comment: Depends on what needs to be changed

Comment: I think no - it wasn't stated in the task. There were only rules that stated that COM is mapped in accordance with: IF A.C1 = 'A' AND A.C2 = 'A1' THEN COM = '1', ELIF A.C1 = 'A' AND A.C2 = 'A2' THEN COM = '2' ... ELIF A.C2 = 'A' THEN COM = '99' if it helps.

Comment: You can mark the question as answered, so that people stop trying to help you.